How can I know the mint address of NFT of candy machine?
I am preparing a project of NFT. I am going to give rewards to owner of my NFTs so I need to make smart contract for that. But my NFTs are in Candy Machine so it has not minted yet. How can I know the address of NFT now to develop smart contract?

You can verify NFTs minted through your Candy Machine by checking their metadata's update authority or fetching all minted NFTs via the Candy Machine ID after minting, and then use this information in your reward-distribution smart contract.

You can't know the NFT addresses before they are minted, but after minting, you can check the metadata of each NFT to verify it was created by your Candy Machine (using the update authority) and then use those addresses in your reward system.
